# Does SSL_free also close the the object's file descriptors? C++ OpenSSL

Tags: c++, networking, openssl

##### Does SSL_free also close the the object's file descriptors? C++ OpenSSL

I could not find this information on https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_free.html.

In case openssl does not close the file descriptor: Should you close the file descriptor(s) like in example 1 or 2? Or even example 3 (unlikely)?

###### Example 1:

```cpp
SSL* ssl = ...;
int fd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
SSL_free(ssl);
close(fd);
```

###### Example 2:

```cpp
SSL* ssl = ...;
int rfd = SSL_get_rfd(ssl);
int wfd = SSL_get_wfd(ssl);
SSL_free(ssl);
close(rfd);
close(wfd);
```

###### Example 3:

```cpp
SSL* ssl = ...;
int fd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
int rfd = SSL_get_rfd(ssl);
int wfd = SSL_get_wfd(ssl);
SSL_free(ssl);
close(fd);
close(rfd);
close(wfd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `close` the file descriptors you get from `SSL_get_fd()` (or `SSL_get_rfd()`/`SSL_get_wfd()`:

> `SSL_free()` also calls the free()ing procedures for indirectly affected items, if applicable: **the buffering BIO, the read and write BIOs**, cipher lists specially created for this ssl, the SSL_SESSION. **Do not explicitly free these** indirectly freed up items before or after calling SSL_free(), as trying to free things twice may lead to program failure.

---

As for the third example: In case `SSL_get_rfd()` and `SSL_get_wfd()` returns different file descriptors, `SSL_get_fd()` returns the same descriptor as `SSL_get_rfd()`.

Comment: Thanks! Therefore I assume you should also not close the underlying socket's file descriptor?

Comment: @user39847589375345 You're welcome! I think that depends on the situation. Is it a socket created by `SSL` calls or manually created? From an SSL perspective, you may `SSL_shutdown()`.

Comment: The socket is created manually with `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)`. Can I therefore assume I should close the underlying socket?

Comment: @user39847589375345 Yes, that would be my guess. If you use this socket with `SSL` you should probably `close` it after the `SSL` session has been `SSL_shutdown`.